# Open intervals of zero length are empty

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was reading a solution to a question and it said "As open intervals of zero length are necessarily empty".

How can an interval be empty? All I'm imagining is $(0,0)$ which doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to write the interval $(a,b)$ is

$$ (a,b) = \{ x : a < x < b \}. $$

Therefore, if we wanted to define $(0,0)$, it would be

$$ (0,0) = \{ x : 0 < x < 0 \}. $$

Since there is no $x$ such that $0 < x < 0$, the set on the right-hand
side is empty.

Similarly, for any real number $a$,

$$ (a,a) = \{ x : a < x < a \} $$

which is an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition of an interval:

$(a, b) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$

$(a, b)$ makes sense for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and in the case of $(0, 0)$, it is the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You even have the following assertion: If $A$ is an open set with measure zero, then $A = \emptyset$. Indeed, if there would be $x \in A$, then also $B_\varepsilon(x) \subset A$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. But the measure of $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is positive, a contradiction.